# What happens to the t-butyl cation in the TFA deprotection of a t-butyl ester?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, carbocation, proteins, protecting-groups

I am a first-year chemistry graduate student and I am currently learning how to synthesize proteins. I have reached a stage in the process where I need to deprotect a carboxylic acid moiety protected by t-butyl using trifluoroacetic acid (TFA).
I went online trying to find the mechanism for this step, but in terms of step-wise mechanism with electron movement arrows, the only thing I was able to find was this:
[image: Deprotection of t-butyl carboxylic acid using TFA]

(Taken from [here](http://www.commonorganicchemistry.com/Rxn_Pages/Boc_Protection/Boc_Protection_TFA_Mech.htm), no references therein)

While this looks legit, I am wondering about the t-butyl cation and its fate. 
My reaction is a bit simpler, and is presented below:
[image: Deprotection of t-butyl with TFA]

And my question is: **is this truly where the deprotection ends? Does the t-butyl cation remains in solution as pictured?**

(I know that a t-butyl cation is considered to be relatively stable on account of it being a tertiary carbocation, but still I was not sure that it can remain in solution like that.)

Comment: Probably gives isobutene, depending on what solvent you're using

Comment: The solvent is dichloromethane. What is its role?

Comment: In which case DCM plays no part as it will not react with tBu+, other solvents may react with it e.g. toluene

Comment: According to a post-doc colleague, step no. 4 IS the final state of the molecules in the solution (i.e. t-butyl can exist in the solution as a cation), but if water will be added to the solution, then the t-butyl cation will take an OH group and the TFA will become protonated. In case anyone was wondering...

Comment: It is worth remembering that when you cleave a tBu ester,  tBu+ can hang around and potentially react with e.g. electron-rich aromatics

Comment: Would tBu+ show up on NMR?

Comment: If you ran your reaction in CD2Cl2 and did an NMR of an aliquot I guess it might. If you concentrate your aliquot first before redissolving in your NMR solvent I think you would lose it as isobutene

Answer (score 2):

I realize this question is old but the mechanism is nicely described here (steps 1-3): [http://www.umich.edu/~chemh215/W06HTML/SSG2/ssg6/main_files/Page346.htm](http://www.umich.edu/%7Echemh215/W06HTML/SSG2/ssg6/main_files/Page346.htm)

Briefly, the released t-butyl carbocation is subsequently deprotonated by the anionic TFA, resulting in the formation of 2-methyl-propene. This regenerates the protonated TFA that is needed to continue the reaction, and thus the TFA is catalytic (i.e. not consumed in the reaction).

Answer (score 1):

The reaction is, in principle, catalytic in TFA. If t-butyltrifluoroacetate is the by-product, then the catalyst is consumed. If only isobutylene is formed, catalytic is OK. Using excess TFA covers all contingencies. In the initial step, protonation is more likely on the C=O oxygen. Higher electron density.